# Unsupported Protocol in Codeigniter Rest Library

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a rest API for an existing database. I was suggested to use Rest API from Chris Kacerguis, but his latest build came up with some constant errors. I decided to then use a prior version that still works but have an "unsupported protocol" error. I copy-pasted the code from his basic GET example and still have the same unsupported protocol error.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use chriskacerguis\RestServer\RestController;

class Api extends RestController {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Construct the parent class
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function users_get()
    {
        // Users from a data store e.g. database
        $users = [
            ['id' => 0, 'name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@example.com'],
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Jim', 'email' => 'jim@example.com'],
        ];

        $id = $this->get( 'id' );

        if ( $id === null )
        {
            // Check if the users data store contains users
            if ( $users )
            {
                // Set the response and exit
                $this->response( $users, 200 );
            }
            else
            {
                // Set the response and exit
                $this->response( [
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'No users were found'
                ], 404 );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( array_key_exists( $id, $users ) )
            {
                $this->response( $users[$id], 200 );
            }
            else
            {
                $this->response( [
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'No such user found'
                ], 404 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Answer (score 1):

Check this option in the REST config file

```
$config['force_https'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue because my site was behind a load balancer and requests were coming into the API from the load balancer as http: (port 80)

the solution was to turn the force_https to off, so:

```
$config['force_https']           = FALSE;
```